# Postgres restore, error in toc relation doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I was prototyping a system in a notebook and its monitor broke. I was able to turn it on and make the backup of my database. Now I am trying to restore it but the error is pretty strange for me. I am trying for hours to solve the problem, I've tried to use PgAdmin 4, tried several options and nothing. I've tried to use the pg_restore.exe tool but its same thing. My last resource is to provide a github repo so you can check it out. The relations doesn't exist. I would love to check if I did something wrong while performing the backup (like not including the tables) but, how I said, my PC is broken. But I am pretty sure I include all I needed.

By the way, I created a table called automoveis on PgAdmin and tried to restore against it. That's the original name in my old computer.

[github sql file of the restore](https://github.com/diegowebuzz/error-restore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `automoveis.sql` file that you shared is a data-only dump--it will not `CREATE TABLE`s for you.  You will have to create your own tables before you can restore this file.  If you have access to the old database, you could try doing `pg_dump --schema-only <database_name>` to get the `CREATE TABLE` statements

Comment: PostgreSQL is one of the best databases but its main IDE is very cofusing and error prone, as far backup is concerned. It could by default come with all the setting one would normally want when performing a database "backup", data and structure.

Comment: @DiegoAlves  That is the default.  I don't how you got into this situation, but it wasn't by following the defaults.  PgAdmin4 may have plenty to complain about, but this is not one of them.